# Como entender a lógica do carrinho de compras em um projeto JSF?

Tags: java-ee, jsf-2.2

Estou desenvolvimento um protótipo de Ecommerce sendo que ainda estou tentando aprender a lógica do carrinho de compras. Por [esse link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCXFwvp9HdU) ou [esse outro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IH5TeMObs2s) de vídeos no Youtube ele faz os seguintes passos:

1. Ele cria um método que consiga captura o registro de acordo com a
   linha selecionada.
2. Depois disso ele atualizar as tabelas via Ajax pelos endereço identificador (id) da tabela que está o registro para a tabela que vai ser adicionada os novos registro aplicando a lógica de carrinho de compras, mas não deixando de salientar que essa maneira somente é possível porque as duas tabelas se encontram na mesma página.

Meu objetivo é pelo menos conseguir capturar a linha selecionada e jogar o registro para outra pagina, mas não consigo imagina uma forma de fazer isso, eu consigo até jogar o endereço identificador da linha selecionada utilizando `:param` como no código abaixo, porém eu não consigo carregar a outra pagina mesmo tendo o endereço identificador.

```jsp
<p:button outcome="/noticias/CarrinhoCompras.xhtml"
    icon="ui-icon-cart " title="Carrinho">
        '
    <f:param name="noticia" value="#{noticia.id}" />
</p:button>
```

Essa foi minha última tentativa colocando esse trecho de código:

```jsp
<p:commandButton value="adicionar"
   action="#{carrinhoComprasBean.adicionar(noticia)}" />
```

E essa é minha classe Bean que lista a tabela:

```java
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class PesquisaNoticiasBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Noticias noticias;

    private NoticiaFilter filtro;
    private List<Noticia> noticiasFiltrados;

    private Noticia noticiaSelecionada;

    public PesquisaNoticiasBean() {
        filtro = new NoticiaFilter();
        noticiasFiltrados = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void pesquisar() {

        noticiasFiltrados = noticias.filtrados(filtro);

    }

    public void inicializar() {
        noticiasFiltrados = noticias.raizes();
    }

    public void excluir(){
        noticias.remover(noticiaSelecionada);
        noticiasFiltrados.remove(noticiaSelecionada);
        FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Noticia " + noticiaSelecionada.getTitulo_noticia() + "excluída com sucesso");
    }

    public List<Noticia> getNoticiasFiltrados() {
        return noticiasFiltrados;
    }

    public NoticiaFilter getFiltro() {
        return filtro;
    }

    public Noticias getNoticias() {
        return noticias;
    }

    public Noticia getNoticiaSelecionada() {
        return noticiaSelecionada;
    }

    public void setNoticiaSelecionada(Noticia noticiaSelecionada) {
        this.noticiaSelecionada = noticiaSelecionada;
    }
}
```

E essa é a classe Bean que trabalha tentando transferir o registro selecionado para a outra tabela na outra pagina:

```java
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CarrinhoComprasBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Noticias noticias;

    private NoticiaFilter filtro;
    private List<Noticia> noticiasFiltrados;

    private List<Item> listaItens = new ArrayList<>();

    private Noticia noticiaSelecionada;

    public CarrinhoComprasBean() {
        filtro = new NoticiaFilter();
        noticiasFiltrados = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void pesquisar() {

        noticiasFiltrados = noticias.filtrados(filtro);

    }


    public String adicionar(Noticia noticia){
       Item item = new Item();
       item.setNoticia(noticia);
       item.setQuantidade(1);
       item.setValor(noticia.getPreco());

       //System.out.println("lista de itens " +item);
       listaItens.add(item);
       return "CarrinhoCompras";
    }

//  public String addcart(Noticia n) {
//      for (Item item : cart) {
//          if (item.getNoticia().getId() == n.getId()) {
//              item.setQuantidade(item.getQuantidade()+1);
//              return "CarrinhoCompras";
//          }
//      }
//      Item i = new Item();
//      i.setQuantidade(1);
//      i.setNoticia(n);
//      cart.add(i);
//      return "CarrinhoCompras";
//  }

    public void inicializar() {
        noticiasFiltrados = noticias.raizes();
    }

    public void excluir() {
        noticias.remover(noticiaSelecionada);
        noticiasFiltrados.remove(noticiaSelecionada);
        FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Noticia " + noticiaSelecionada.getTitulo_noticia() + "excluída com sucesso");
    }

    public List<Noticia> getNoticiasFiltrados() {
        return noticiasFiltrados;
    }

    public NoticiaFilter getFiltro() {
        return filtro;
    }

    public Noticias getNoticias() {
        return noticias;
    }

    public Noticia getNoticiaSelecionada() {
        return noticiaSelecionada;
    }

    public void setNoticiaSelecionada(Noticia noticiaSelecionada) {
        this.noticiaSelecionada = noticiaSelecionada;
    }

    public List<Item> getListaItens() {
        return listaItens;
    }

    public void setListaItens(List<Item> listaItens) {
        this.listaItens = listaItens;
    }
}
```

Esse é o método em questão:

```java
public String adicionar(Noticia noticia){
    Item item = new Item();
    item.setNoticia(noticia);
    item.setQuantidade(1);
    item.setValor(noticia.getPreco());

    //System.out.println("lista de itens " +item);
    listaItens.add(item);
    return "CarrinhoCompras";
}
```

Para quem quiser ter acesso ao meu código completo está aqui [meu projeto no GitHub](https://github.com/wladyband/VendeLancha/tree/master/VendeLancha/src/main/webapp/noticias).

Preciso muito de ajuda.

Seguindo a sugestão proposta foi modificado o método na classe CarrinhoCompraBean;

```
public String adicionar(Noticia noticia){
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setNoticia(noticia);
        item.setQuantidade(1);
        item.setValor(noticia.getPreco());

        // está aqui o código para imprimir
        System.out.println("lista de itens " +item);



        listaItens.add(item);
        return "CarrinhoCompras";
    }
```

Essa foi a mensagem que saiu no consoles do eclipse no primeiro item da lista na dataTable

```
lista de itens br.com.vendelancha.model.Item@6b10199b
```

No segundo item da lista do dataTable saiu esse

```
lista de itens br.com.vendelancha.model.Item@53404bd1
```

e foi assim que ficou o botão adicionar

```
            <p:commandButton value="adicionar"
                action="#{carrinhoComprasBean.adicionar(noticia)}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{carrinhoComprasBean.noticiaSelecionada}"
                    value="#{noticia}" />
            </p:commandButton>
```

Quando foi clicado aconteceu os fatos acima descritos e em seguida foi direcionado para a outra pagina, porém não conseguir carregar a datable com o item clicado, pois é esse o objetivo, clicar no item e esse item for adicionado na outra tabela na outra pagina.

Ele está nessa tela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e foi para essa tela, não tendo resultado como pode ver.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse botão está dentro de uma coluna?

Comment: positivo, se você observar verá que está dentro de uma coluna.

Comment: Observar aonde, pois no código não está muito claro rsrs. Enfim, tente usar o `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` passando o seu objeto selecionado

Comment: eu já tentei isso, mas eu fiz isso sem pedir ajuda, mas eu vou colocar de novo como tenha feito e solicito que possa persistir em mim ajudar. daqui a pouco vou atualizar minhas postagem.

Comment: Quando atualizar a postagem me avisa que posto uma possível solução pro seu problema.

Comment: acabei de atualizar a postagem.

Comment: Já tentou usar o evento rowSelect da <p:dataTable> ?

Comment: Não conheço, vou ver o que se tratar.

Comment: acabei ver, eu tentei, mas não tive sucesso.

Comment: Pronto, você já consegue pegar o objeto certo? você quer passar esse objeto para outra página agora?

Comment: sim, claro que quero

Comment: Vamos por parte, seu código é muito grande e ainda não está claro. Você quer passar um objeto ou uma lista para a outra página?

Comment: Quero fazer semelhante ao vídeo  >>>>>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IH5TeMObs2s

Comment: qual vai ser a diferença de passar o objeto ou passa a lista?

Comment: Não posso assistir o vídeo no momento, se você passa o Objeto é apenas um item, se você passa uma lista são vários itens

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de você mandar um objeto ou uma lista dela para outra pagina é assim:

Por exemplo no seu método `adicionar()` adicione o seguinte código:

```
List<Noticia> lista = new ArrayList<>();  
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("lista", lista);
```

e para recuperar a lista na sua outra pagina(ou outro bean):

```
List<Noticia> pegaLista = (List<Noticia>) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("lista");
```

Comment: E as paginas iram ficar do jeito como elas estão? Somente devo fazer essas alteração nas classes e pronto?

Comment: Desculpe, mas isso não ficou bem explicado. Como eu vou colocar o código? aonde colocar o código?

Comment: Então não sei como está seu código, mas se tiver um Bean para cada página, o primeiro trecho você pode colocar no seu método para redirecionar a página e quando você redirecionar poder usar um método de init() com notação @PostConstruct(ela vai fazer a configuração inicial pro seu bean) e pegar a lista com o segundo trecho.

Comment: Não é possível colocar um @PostConstruct porque estou usando CDI no projeto, mas se tivesse visto meu projeto no GitHub não teria esses desencontros.

Answer (score 1):

Para esse seu problema, você pode continuar enviando o id pelo param, só que na outra página você terá que fazer o seguinte.
Adicione a tag  da forma como está a seguir.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="noticia" converter="noticiaConverter"
            value="#{bean.noticia}"/> </f:metadata>
```

você vai precisar criar um converter que busque a noticia pelo id passado como parâmetro e retorne o objeto para o objeto noticia do seu bean.